# Switch from VOLUME_KMSCLIENT to RETAIL channel

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

On my laptop I had Windows 8 Pro KMS activated, then I intalled WMC, which changed it to RETAIL channel, so I don't need KMS

I repeated this on my desktop, which was VOLUME_KMSCLIENT and I thought it would convert it to RETAIL, but now it's just Windows 8 Pro WMC KMS.

slmgr -dli partial p.key doesn't match that one I entered

I can't update to 8.1 (through win store) when I have VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel.
How do I change it?

edit:

wmc key that I used is blocked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a legal valid key to convert it to Retail, to be able to see 8.1 update in Store.

Comment: so just any valid non-VL key will convert it to RETAIL?

Comment: yes, and since will make it retail , you will be able to see 8.1 update in store.

Comment: or if you have MSDN subscription , you can get there 8.1 pro_vl ISO, and you can do upgrade or fresh install , official kms keys here (for install only): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612867.aspx